# What could be limiting my maximum upload file size on my Raspberry Pi LAMP stack?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, raspberry-pi, lamp

So I have a LAMP webserver hosted on a Raspberry Pi 3. The Raspberry Pi has a RAID 10 connected to it through a hardware RAID controller. My goal is to be able to  upload large files through my webpage using PHP via a LAMP stack setup on the Raspberry Pi.

I am able to successfully upload a file that is 0.97G but not one that is 1.32G so something must be limiting my upload file size to approximately 1G is my guess.

In php.ini I have the following set right now:

- `memory_limit`: 1000M
- `post_max_size`: 4G
- `upload_max_filesize`: 4G
- `upload_tmp_dir`: `/mnt/raid10/Files/Temp` (This is on the connected RAID so it isn't just dump the file to the SD card that the Raspberry Pi uses. Note that adding this *did* help up the max size from the before lower on.)

I can't figure out which other settings I should try adjusting and am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Which webserver are you using to host the site? That may also have a maximum file size limit.

Comment: The Pi3 has 1GB of physical RAM onboard.  My guess is that that is a limiting factor.

Comment: Try restarting Apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`. It may not have picked up the changes from php.ini yet. [This](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) is the only reference to an Apache specific configuration I see, but is pretty outdated.

Comment: Are you trying to upload locally, and how long is this taking?  Another possibiity is you are running foul of the max_execution time.

Comment: @davidgo https://superuser.com/questions/1351721/cannot-upload-files-larger-than-1gb-in-php-under-apache-even-with-post-max-size/1351727?noredirect=1#comment2026741_1351727 Per the answer there, it seems that the memory limit should not affect the upload size as it is a direct stream. I thought the same thing which is why I posted this originally. Let me try increasing the max_execution time though

Comment: @EricF I was just reading more on that subject, and was about to point out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777624/configuring-apache-for-large-uploads which shows a way to process files in PHP without running into the memory limit -I believe the standard upload mechanism does try hold the whole thing in memory.

Comment: max_execution time = 200000 (I assume this is seconds?)

Comment: Have a look at https://www.plupload.com/ - I've never experienced your problem not used this, but this seems to be touted as a solution (ie its solves the size problem by using "Chunking")

Comment: @davidgo That is a great idea to try. My download handler looks like this one https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php where the chunk size by default seems to be set to 10MB

Comment: @davidgo That works! which must mean that it WAS / IS using the memory when uploading. I added maxChunkSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, to my #fileupload function and it now does it in the corresponding chunk size. If you want to write it up as an answer I will accept it otherwise I can either way. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks for the opportunity to write it up - its probably better if you do it, as it was just educated guesswork on my part, and its sounds like you have actually implemented a solution, so are in a better place to answer.

Comment: @JakeGould SD card is 12 GB or so but I put the temp directory to the RAID which is 2 TB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Removing upload file size limitations**

In order to configure a LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) setup that allows a user to upload large files to their server the following has to be done:

Change the following variables in `php.ini`

1. `memory_limit` = 1000M - Set memory limit to what is available on the system
2. `post_max_size` = 4G - Ensure that this value is greater or equal to the `upload_max_filesize` value
3. `upload_max_filesize` = 4G - Set this to whatever you want the maximum to be
4. `upload_tmp_dir:` `/mnt/raid10/Files/Temp` - By default this is disabled which makes the temporary location be on the same disk as the OS is installed. In my case of running everything off of a Raspberry Pi, that makes it the SD card. To have less restriction, I set this to my network drive location instead.

After doing the above, the limitation in file upload size is the physical memory available to the device, whatever is set for `memory_limit`, and the file system limitations (4GB for a FAT file structure). In the case of my Raspberry Pi 3, that was 1GB.

**Bypassing the memory limit to upload a file bigger than the amount of memory available**

The only way to go past the memory limit is to chunk the upload. Once chunking is enabled, what happens during an upload is the following:

1. Upload initiated on webpage.
2. Data from source file is streamed to the memory of webserver.
3. Data is dumped from memory of webserver to temporary file location.
4. Once the temporary file reaches the chunk size that was set, then that data is dumped into the final destination location file and the temp file is deleted.
5. Repeat step 2 until file is completed.

**How to use chunking**

If you are using a download handler similar to this one (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php) then there are many built in options available.

In my case, where the #fileupload is declared, I added a line for `maxChunkSize`:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    maxChunkSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, // 10 MB <-----This is the line I added
    add: function (e, data) {
       blah blah blah
    }
    });
}
});
```

Whatever value is placed here will be the chunk size used. The size that you chose takes a little experimentation as one that is tiny will slow down the upload speed quite a bit, and one too large will result in the user of the site seeing no progress on their progress bar for quite some time. For me 10MB was a happy medium.

*Do note that the progress bar for the upload will move only when each chunk starts, so it becomes more choppy than a nice continuous progress bar but I am actually ok with this.